# Did the people of Trost District evacuate when the breach in Wall Rose happened?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In volume 9 of *Attack on Titan*, when Wall Rose was breached, did the people of Trost evacuate to Wall Sina along with the settlers who lived in the southwest area (like Connie and Sasha's village) of Wall Rose? Or was it just the settlers that evacuated, for they were the ones closest to the breach?

Comment: IIRC, there was no breach in Wall Rose.... The titans that appeared, were the people of the villages near the wall.... A proof being Connie on reaching his home, was welcomed by a titan whose face resembled that of his mother (lying on top of his home).

Comment: @PratyushManocha Yes but within volume 9 they did not know yet about what truly happened, they were still on the mission of finding the so called "breach" they thought happened, so I was wondering if they spent time into helping the people in trost district to evacuate to the next wall or not. Now that I think of it, it would probably be unlikely

Comment: Yeah. All the villagers had been turned to titans. At least that's what's logical since I don't remember reading them helping anyone evacuate from near the Wall Rose....